# How can I see an MSI file's PackageCode

Tags: windows-installer

I have a .msi file and I need to see it's PackageCode.
I have tried to find it using Orca with no luck.
The .msi file ungrades a product that is not installed on my system, so I cannot run it to see what it puts in the registry.
I would expect Orca to show it - maybe I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package code is shown on the Summary Information dialog: `View|Summary Information`.

Answer (score 2):

***Orca***: The package code can be found using Orca - as Bob Arnson describes - by opening the MSI and going View => Summary Information... => Package Code (towards the bottom).

[image: Orca Dialog]

***Windows Explorer***: However, you can also find the package code without Orca. You open Windows Explorer and locate the MSI. Then you right click it and select "Properties". Now go to "Details" (you can only find the package code like this - not the product code or upgrade code - use Orca instead if you need them - look in the Property table for those values):

[image: Package Code]

***Installed Products***: If the MSI is installed, you can retrieve the package code, product code and upgrade code by various methods. Here is a script that will export an HTML-report: https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs

Sample screenshot:

[image: HTML export]

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it must be an optional field in the properties -> details view of the file.  In my case it is not there.

Comment: As long as you find it in the MSI file itself with Orca you are fine - if the package code is missing inside the MSI, then that is very bad news for the use of the MSI file.